# Table alignment

Tags: tables

I want to ask how I can align this table so all the binary data are all exactly under the corresponding headers "x_i"?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering}m{#1}}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{C{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Table Title}‎
\centering
‎\begin{tabular}{||c c c||}
‎\hline‎
\text{$‎\mathcal{C}-x_1‎$‎‎}  &  \text{$‎\mathcal{C}^x_1‎$} & \text{$‎tail_{x_1}
(\mathcal{C})‎$}\\ [0.5ex]‎
‎\hline\hline‎
‎$‎x_2‎$ ‎‎$‎x_3‎$ ‎‎$‎x_4‎$‎   &    $‎x_2‎$ ‎‎$‎x_3‎$ ‎‎$‎x_4‎$  &    ‎$‎x_1$ $‎x_2‎$ ‎‎$‎x_3‎$ ‎‎$‎x_4‎$ \\ 
[0.5ex]‎
‎\hline\hline‎
‎0 0 0    &    0 0 0    &    0 1 0 1    \\ [0.5ex]‎
‎0 1 0    &    ‎0 1 0    &    ‎0 1 1 0    \\ [0.5ex]‎
‎0 1 1    &    ‎0 1 1    &    0 1 1 1    \\ [0.5ex]‎
1 0 0    &    1 0 0    &                  \\ [0.5ex]‎
‎1 0 1    &               &                  \\ [0.5ex]‎
1 1 0    &               &                  \\ [0.5ex]‎ 
1 1 1    &               &                  \\ [0.5ex]‎           
         &               &                   \\ [1ex]‎
‎\hline‎  ‎‎
\bottomrule[1.25pt]
\end {tabular}
\\[10pt]
\caption*{See This}
\end{table}‎ \vspace{0.5cm}‎ ‎

\end{document}
```

Comment: please, provide MWE!

Comment: Excuse me, but I don't know what does "MWE" means!

Comment: Minimum Working Example

Comment: It means to provide code starting with `\documentclass`, and then list the relevant `\usepackage` calls and other initializations, continues with `\begin{document}` and a small bit of compileable code capable of demonstrating the issue, followed by `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Aref, sorry bit according to your reputation I (wrongly) assume, that you already familiar with MWE.

Comment: I added what you want, I assume.

Comment: Your code can't be compile for encoding reasons. Are you sure it's utf8 encoded? There are “unicode characters not set up for LaTeX”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In math testbed I compose code for following table:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\newcommand\mcx[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{$#2$}}

\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\caption{Table title}
\label{tab:codetable}
    \centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{tabular}{*{12}{>{\ttfamily}c}}
    \toprule
\mcx{3}{\mathcal{C} - x_1} &
    &   \mcx{3}{\mathcal{C}^x_1} &
        &  \mcx{4}{\text{tail}_{x_1}(\mathcal{C})}   \\
$x_2$ & $x_3$ & $x_4$ &
    & $x_2$ & $x_3$ & $x_4$ &
        & $x_1$ & $x_2$ & $x_3$ & $x_4$              \\
    \cmidrule{1-3}
    \cmidrule{5-7}
    \cmidrule{9-12}
0 & 0 & 0  &&  0 & 0 & 0   &&  0 & 1 & 0 & 1            \\
0 & 1 & 0  &&  0 & 1 & 0   &&  0 & 1 & 1 & 0            \\
0 & 1 & 1  &&  0 & 1 & 1   &&  0 & 1 & 1 & 1            \\
1 & 0 & 0  &&  1 & 0 & 0   &&    &   &   &              \\
1 & 0 & 1  &&    &   &     &&    &   &   &              \\
1 & 1 & 0  &&    &   &     &&    &   &   &              \\
1 & 1 & 1  &&    &   &     &&    &   &   &              \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\dots, see table \ref{tab:codetable}.
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
I had problems with your code. It seems that it contain hidden character or unknown coded characters  which caused problems to my editor. That is main reason that I like to see preamble of your document. Now, hopefully I solve this problem (by retyping your code) :-)

Comment: C'mon, help us out.  What is `\mcx`?

Comment: I have problems with OP code. it seems that (s)he use in editor a coding which is not compatible with my editor, so now I need to retype (collect) preamble from my "testbed". this will take some (short) time `\newcommand\mcx[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{$#2$}}`